# Magento 2 get contact form

Tags: magento2, programmatically, contact-form

In Magento 1. I have the following code:

```
$form =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock("core/template")->setTemplate("contacts/form.phtml")->toHtml();
```

Need Help something similar for Magento 2

Comment: Can you describe use cases? Your example looks strange for me.

Answer (score 1):

For magento 2.x try this

```
    $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm')
->setTemplate()->setTemplate("Magento_Contact::form.phtml")->toHtml()
```